# Linq query for updating list of objects with some data from another list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of two objects:

`IList<DetailsObject>`

and

`IList<UpdatesObject>` containing updates.

Common distinct field in both objects is ID, and `UpdatesObject` field is just a subset of all `DetailsObject` fields.

Can I use Linq method to update `DetailsObject` with values from `UpdatesObject`. I know the easiest solution would be to iterate over `UpdatesObject` and in each iteration find object where IDs match, and then update what is necessary.

```
foreach(UpdatesObject uobj in IList<UpdatesObject>)
{
    foreach(DetailsObject dobj in IList<DetailsObject>)
    {
        if (uobj.ID == dobj.ID)
        {
            dobj.Detail1 = uobj.Detail1;
            dobj.Detail2 = uobj.Detail2;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve it without such a nested loop?

Comment: Maybe there is a better way to handle object updates?

Answer (score 3):

You can join two lists based on ID column then use a foreach loop to update your objects:

```
var objects = from u in UpdatesObject
              join d in DetailsObject on u.ID equals d.ID
              select new { Update = u, Detail = d };

foreach(var obj in objects)
{
    obj.Detail.Detail1 = obj.Update.Detail1;
    obj.Detail.Detail2 = obj.Update.Detail2;
}
```